# Pathologic breaks my external links

Tags: 7, input-formats

My basic page is using a wysiwyg editor (ckeditor) which is filtered by pathologic to generate links that uses my pathauto aliases. This is great. My problem is with external links. Somehow, pathologic detect those links as a broken internal link and replaces the external domain with its local domain...

ex: my site is on domain.com and on a page's wysiwyg field I am putting an external link to anotherdomainwehost.com/about/us.

This is changed by pathologic to "domain.com/about/us" which is completely wrong!

How can I fix this? Somehow pathologic thinks that anotherdomainwehost.com is the same web site as domain.com. I don't know why and can't find where are those configured.

I found no where in my installation a way to edit the pathologic settings. I went to the [Pathologic page](https://www.drupal.org/node/257026) but can't find the provided link. I have no "Pathologic" option in the Content Authoring menu...

I am willing to hack the damn thing, whether it is in the code or in the db if someone tells me where to look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pathologic settings are on the text format.  So you'd go here: admin/config/content/formats and click "configure" next to the format you want to tweak.  If it's a format that has Pathologic selected for it, then you will see a "Correct URLs with Pathologic" vertical tab down near the bottom of the page.  The settings are in there.

It sounds like you have anotherdomainwehost.com in the list of "all base paths for this site".